# How to select all (not only from first page) rows programatically in vue good table Remote Mode?

Tags: vue.js, vue-good-table

I'm trying to do something like this:

[image]

[image]

any advice very welcome

https://xaksis.github.io/vue-good-table/guide/advanced/checkbox-table.html#checkbox-table

Answer (score 0):

You will not do this in interface. You save a variable and send it to your API, telling it to apply that modification to all data.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible in vue good table. Check this for your reference. You can use slots though

https://github.com/xaksis/vue-good-table/issues/237